# using azure ad authentication extension for the vm gives error

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-active-directory

Using Azure AD Authentication extension for the VM gives the below error

**Connection closed by vm_private_ip port 22**

couple of things:

1. I have full permissions to the VM (VM Admin Login Permission)
2. The VM is running
3. Port 22 is open (telnet works)
4. ssh via a pem key works

Can anyone please help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [login into your Linux Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad#log-in-to-the-linux-virtual-machine) with your Azure Ad account, you can use the public IP of Azure VM instead of private IP.

To view the **public IP address** of your VM with `az vm show`:

```
az vm show --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myVM -d --query publicIps -o tsv
```

Replace the example IP address with the **public IP addres**s of your VM from the previous command.

```
ssh -l azureuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com 10.11.123.456(example IP)
```

You are prompted to sign in to Azure AD with a one-time use code at `https://microsoft.com/devicelogin`. Copy and paste the one-time **use code** into the device login page.

When prompted, enter your Azure AD login credentials at the login page.
Close the browser window, return to the SSH prompt, and press the **Enter** key.
[image]

**Note**: you should not connect to your Azure VM with the commands `ssh -l` in the Azure cloud shell because it will not prompt you to sign in to Azure AD after my validation. It just keeps time out.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. Seems like the VM doesn't have a Public IP. I have complete Azure Portal access and can see the VM's specification

Comment: Where do you want to ssh into your Azure VM? Is it from your local network environment? If so, you need a VPN gateway to connect the local network and Azure network. When you said "ssh via a pem key works", Where and how do you ssh? Or in this case, you can assign a public IP to the VM interface, then you can ssh vm with public IP address.

Comment: Here "ssh via pem key works" was to indicate that they were in the same network and I could reach the machine from my localhost.
Looks like it is an issue with the Azure AD extension that is attached to the VM. I have raised a ticket for the same with Azure Support team.

Comment: I suppose you have two VMs in the same Azure network, then you want to ssh into another VM from one VM with a private Ip address. When you try to ssh with an Azure AD account. Is there a prompted UI to allow you to sign in to Azure AD account?

Comment: yes, i am prompted to the ui but the connection closes as soon as authentication is done

Comment: Do you check if your VMs network configuration meets [Network requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad#network-requirements)?

Comment: yes, the configuration is met. Looks like it is an extension issue. I have raised a ticket with the azure team. Thanks for helping me out!